# Insert custom post type via XML-RPC?

Tags: custom-post-types, xml-rpc

I am trying to connect to my wordpress installation in order to create posts of a specific kind. The code I am using for that is:

```
Include('../wp-includes/class-IXR.php');
$client = new IXR_Client('http://www.example.com/xmlrpc.php');


        $content = array(
            'title' => 'Test',
            'description' => 'content',
            'mt_allow_comments' => 0, // 1 to allow comments
            'mt_allow_pings' => 0, // 1 to allow trackbacks
            'post_type' => 'question',
            'mt_keywords' => 'test'
        );




if (!$client->query('metaWeblog.newPost','', 'admin','pass', $content, publish)) {
    die('An error occurred - '.$client->getErrorCode().":".$client->getErrorMessage());
}
echo $client->getResponse();    //with Wordpress, will report the ID of the new post
```

When I try this code I get the following error:

```
An error occurred - 401:Invalid post type
```

I am positive `question` is a valid post type so I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: how is "question" registered?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am not entirely sure because it is part of a theme I bought. What I see is the following URL when I click on the menu http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=question I am trying to find the piece of code where 'question' is registered, but it might take me a while. Thanks for your time, and if you have any clues I will appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The wp.* methods](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) that were added in WP 4.3 support custom post types. [The old metaWeblog methods](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_MetaWeblog_API) did not.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the same in the docs. I found some other answerds saying that it should work by setting 'post_type' to my type (other than post or page), but it looks it changed.

Comment: You're looking at the [old `metaWeblog` methods](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_MetaWeblog_API), the [new `wp.*` methods](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) support custom post types.

Comment: I would like to post a side note: JSON API seems to be the future. Does new applications should be developed with it and old applications should move from XML-RPC to JSON API? In general, I think so.